# How to show categories in a treeview in Yii

Tags: yii, treeview

I have a category model with this structure:

```
id,name,parent_id
```

I want to display categories in a treeview in Yii. As I found there is a widget called 'CTreeView' but I cannot find an clear example how to use it.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is not much tour for CTreeView. But You can look here

- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/?tag=ctreeview
- [Generating tree from database in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815467/generating-tree-from-database-in-yii)
- http://www.yiiplayground.com/index.php?r=UiModule/ui_other/treeView

Comment: Please try to put the essential information in the answer itself, i.e. an example how to use `CTreeView`. You can use links to provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Download Extension**
[Download AIOTree](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tree-extension/files/tree.v2.zip)

**2. Extract it & put in your extension directory of yii project(extension/AIOTree/your extract files)**

**3. Now add this code at any where you want**

```
<?php
   $data=array(
     '1'=>array('parentid'=>'','text'=>'One'),
     '2'=>array('parentid'=>'','text'=>'Two'),
     '3'=>array('parentid'=>'','text'=>'Three'),
     '11'=>array('parentid'=>'1','text'=>'One-One'),
     '12'=>array('parentid'=>'1','text'=>'One-Two'),        
   );
  // AIOTree
  Yii::import("application.extensions.AIOTree.*");
  $this->Widget('AIOTree',array(    
    'data'=>$data,
  ));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create array with your data from database and use it in CTreeView widget

```
    // Your array with data

    $data = array(
        array(
            'text' => 'Node 1',
            'expanded' => true, // expanded branch or not (true by default)
            'children' => array(
                array('text' => 'Node 1.1'),   
                array('text' => 'Node 1.),   
                array('text' => 'Node 1.3')
            )
        ),

    );

    // In your view call widget 

    $this->widget('CTreeView', array('data' => $data));
```

See more widget capability in offical documentatio: (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTreeView)